# When I assign a texture, it appears in the preview but not on selected faces

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I have several faces assigned to a material slot. However, when I try to assign a texture to it, the texture appears in the little preview box but does not appear on the faces. They slightly change color but do not show the actual texture.

---

Here is what I am doing:

- Assign faces to material slot
- Go to Shading tab
- Make sure that the right material slot is selected
- Drag texture image from file into the node area
- Make a link from "color" to "base color".

At this point the faces slightly change color. I even tested this exact approach in a new project on a plain cube and it worked!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question and add images and any other information that would be useful for others to answer your question.

Comment: Did you create UVs? If you are not defining coordinates with a texture coordinate nodes, then the default mapping for image textures is UV mapping.

Comment: First thing to check is UVs. If you need help you can upload the blend file. I could take a look.